# sign extension using concatenation

Tags: concatenation, verilog, system-verilog, signed, sign-extension

I need to make sign extension from a 4-bit number to a 32-bit number.
 I try to repeat the MSB 28 times like this:

```
assign x={28'b{a[3]},a[3:0]};
```

But, I get an error:

> Syntax error near "{"

`x` is defined as :`wire [31:0] x ;`

`a` is defined as : `input [3:0]a;`

Is this concatenation wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You need to get rid of the `'b` and add another pair of `{}`:

```
assign x = { {28{a[3]}}, a};
```

Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), section 11.4.12.1 "Replication operator".